# WebSockets code not sending/receiving messages

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket

I need to send WebSocket messages from my backend application (Spring Boot) to my frontend application (Angular). Currently, these are the WebSocket-related classes in my code.

*pom.xml* (also `npm install @stomp/stompjs ws` on the Angular frontend)

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

*WebSocketConfig.java*

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/mywebsocket")
    .withSockJS();
  }
}
```

*MessageSenderService.java*

```java
@Service
public class MessageSenderService {

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

    public MessageSenderService(SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate) {
        this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/messages", message);
    }
}
```

This is my back-end business logic code that should be able to send messages.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    MyClass myObject;

    // This is called from the Angular frontend
    @PostMapping("/frontEnd")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> myRequest(@RequestBody HashMap<String, Object> request) throws MalformedURLException {
        // This should send a message on the WebSocket
        myObject.myMethod();
    }
}
```

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    MessageSenderService messageSenderService;

    public void myMethod() {
        try {
            messageSenderService.sendMessage("Test message");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Then, I try to intercept the message sent over WebSocket from the back-end inside my front-end app, with the following code:

```js
export class WebsocketComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const client = new Client({
      brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8080/mywebsocket',
      webSocketFactory: () => new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/mywebsocket'),
      onConnect: () => {
        client.subscribe('/topic/messages', message =>
          console.log(`Received: ${message.body}`)
        );
        client.publish({ destination: '/topic/messages', body: 'First Message' });
      },
    });

  }
}
```

However, the front-end never receives anything, even after `messageSenderService.sendMessage("Test message")` is called without errors. But I'm not even sure that the message is being sent, all I know is that the method call completes without any error. Any ideas?